# HAProxy Multiport backends

Tags: haproxy

I may be using the wrong terms to search, but I'm having trouble finishing connections to my backend servers though HAProxy. I am able to initially login to the servers, but then the application communicates through two others ports as well. I can go directly to one of the servers and it logs in and lunches the application correctly. Through HAProxy however, I can authenticate, and then I get a communication error. I'm thinking that HAProxy is not passing through data on the other ports. How can this be achieved?

My setup:

2 HAProxy server connected to 2 identical VM servers. HAProxy seems to be working correctly as far as telling when the service on the mcahines are running. It is passing through authentication on port 8443. But that's as far as it will go. It will not launch the VM which uses ports 3000 and 5432. Any ideas on the HAProxy setup?

Here is my configuration file:

```
global
    ssl-server-verify none
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
    maxconn 256

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    timeout connect  5000
    timeout client  10000
    timeout server  10000

    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

listen vm-port-3000
    bind *:5432

    server qvd4 10.0.0.1:3000
    server qvdnode02 10.0.0.2:3000

listen vm-port-5432
    bind *:5432

    server qvd4 10.0.0.1:5432
    server qvdnode02 10.0.0.2:5432

listen stats
    bind :1936

    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats realm Loadbalanced\ Servers
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    stats auth haproxy:haproxy


frontend vm-initial-conn
    bind *:8443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/qvd/haproxy.pem

    default_backend vmConn

backend vmConn
    option forwardfor
    option httpchk GET /qvd/ping HTTP/1.1
    http-check expect status 200
    balance roundrobin

    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]

    server qvd4 10.0.0.1:8443 ssl verify none check
    server qvdnode02 10.0.0.2:8443 ssl verify none check
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think this has anything to do with different ports. For some reason, HAProxy is timing out. Still investigating.

Answer (score 0):

In your `vm-port-3000` you are actually binding to port `5432` instead of how it appears you intended to port 3000.

Thus, requests to port 5432 are randomly handled by either your `vm-port-3000` or your `vm-port-5432` listener while connections to port 3000 are not handled by HAProxy at all.